# add "map lead fields" to change set?

Tags: force.com, change-set

We're mapping lead fields using the "map leads fields." Can these mappings be included in a change set? I don't see this as an option in doing change sets from the drop down. How do you guys usually migrate these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Metadata API Developer's Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/), lead settings cannot be retrieved or deployed. In addition, the documentation does not state any way to migrate these settings. It is presumed that the documentation does not cover this because it cannot currently be done.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a way to deploy Lead Field Mapping through Git.
Now there is a metadata type to deploy Lead Mapping, please refer to the documentation:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_leadconvertsettings.htm?_ga=2.175799266.1171729325.1686567919-26591567.1657108165