# Lead:Contact Mapping in managed package

Tags: managed-package, field-mapping

Is it possible to include a lead to contact field mapping in a managed package?

I'm seeing `Field Mapping` as an a choice for components to add but the choices seem odd:

- `Account_Geo_Clean_Rule_for_Billing_AddressOutputMapping` ->  `Account`
- `Account_Geo_Clean_Rule_for_Shipping_AddressOutputMapping` ->  `Account`
- `Contact_Geo_Clean_Rule_for_Mailing_AddressOutputMapping` ->  `Contact`
- `Lead_Geo_Clean_Rule_for_AddressOutputMapping` -> `Lead`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't actually think this is possible.  I have worked on a manage package before that could have benefited from this feature.  Since it was not available, we made it part of the setup process to manually configure the field mappings in the install org after the package was installed.

There is a related question below regarding accessing lead conversion mappings from the metadata API and/or via change set and that does not seem possible either.

see: [add "map lead fields" to change set?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14523/add-map-lead-fields-to-change-set)